# How to print out a Hash table in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, hashtable

I have a code, in which a Hashtable is created using java.util.Hashtable();
Now, I'm gonna know how to see the content of that table, i.e. how to print out that Hashtable?

Comment: To print a hashtable, you need to loop through it. Simple code to iterate the hashtable and pint out the key value pairs should be easy to write.

Comment: Could you explain more?
What do you mean by 'iterate' the hashtable?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate means to loop through, to go through one by one in a collection.

Here is a code example.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class IterateHashtable {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        // creating myHash object 
        Hashtable<String, String> myHash = new Hashtable<String, String>(); 
 
        // adding key-value pairs to myHash
        myHash.put("Apple", "Red");
        myHash.put("Banana", "Yellow");
        myHash.put("Guava", "Green");
 
 
        // Get entrySet() and Iterate using for-each loop
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : myHash.entrySet()) {
             System.out.println("Fruit : " + entry1.getKey() + " Color : " + entry1.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```